# Foursquare "Invalid geo coordinates" error

Tags: foursquare

I'm getting an error `Invalid geo coordinates` when using the following Foursquare API search URL:

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=REMOVED&client_secret=REMOVED&ll=174.696603,-36.916037&query=sushi&v=20170310&m=foursquare`

The coordinates `174.696603,-36.916037` are valid.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could I give you helpful answer?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Have just come back and seen your response and that solved my problem. Edit: Have marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably set the latitude and longitude in reverse. The latitude must be a number between -90 and 90 and the longitude between -180 and 180.

Use the following URL:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=REMOVED&client_secret=REMOVED&ll=-36.916037,174.696603&query=sushi&v=20170310&m=foursquare